# How to model a shared layer in AutoKeras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, automl, auto-keras

I want to share a layer between for two inputs:

```
x --> F(x)
            ==> G(F(x),F(y))
y --> F(y)
```

In Keras, it can be done by defining a layer then passing two inputs separately to the layer, is it possible to do it in AutoKeras?